# How to GROUP BY in groups of N rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, ado

I have a table called `PEOPLE` with the following data:

```
MYNAME    AGE     MYDATE
==========================
MARIO     20      2015/02/03
MARIA     10      2015/02/02
PEDRO     40      2015/02/01
JUAN      15      2015/01/03
PEPE      20      2015/01/02
JULIA     30      2015/01/01
JUANI     50      2014/02/03
MARTIN    10      2014/02/03
NASH      21      2014/02/03
```

Then I want to get the average of age grouping the people in groups of 3 ordering by `MYDATE` descending.
I mean, the result that I'm looking for would be something like:

```
23,3 
21,6 
27
```

Where `23,3` is the average of the age of:

```
MARIO   20      2015/02/03
MARIA   10      2015/02/02
PEDRO   40      2015/02/01
```

And `21,6` is the average of the age of:

```
JUAN    15      2015/01/03
PEPE    20      2015/01/02
JULIA   30      2015/01/01
```

And `27` is the average of the age of:

```
JUANI   50      2014/02/03
MARTIN  10      2014/02/03
NASH    21      2014/02/03
```

How could I handle this? I know how to use `GROUP BY` but only to group for a particular field of the table.

Comment: How do you define first three rows i mean what is the order to say first 3 rows

Comment: Sorry, the order is `MYDATE` descending. Thanks!

Comment: btw was this definitely meant to be a mysql question? In regards to `ado` and the `over` usage in an answer. Not that ado can't be mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL tables are inherently unordered, so I assume that you want to order by `mydate` descending.  You can enumerate the rows using variables, use arithmetic to define the groups, and then get the average:

```
select avg(age)
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) vars
      order by mydate desc
     ) t
group by floor((seqnum - 1) / 3);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! BTW, do you know if `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5` would bear this query? I'm afraid I have to run this through VB6 to a csv file...

Answer (score 1):

Try - You can also then use Grp to get which three people the average relates to

```
select MYNAME, AGE, MYDATE, RN / 3 As Grp into #x
from
(select MYNAME, AGE , MYDATE, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by MyDate) + 2 as RN
from MYdata)x

select Grp, AVG(Age) as AvgAge
From #x
Group By Grp
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't test it right now, but could I avoid saving the data in a variable. I mean, something like this: `select AVG(Age) as AvgAge
From (
    select MYNAME, AGE, MYDATE, RN / 3 As Grp
    from (
        select MYNAME, AGE , MYDATE, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by MyDate desc) + 2 as RN
        from table1
        )
    )
Group By Grp`

Comment: yes you can I thought you might need to get back to the underlying names

Comment: And what is the difference between this `over(order by MyDate)` and this `order by MyDate`?

Comment: This is part of the row number expression ROW_NUMBER() over(order by MyDate desc) which in my example numbers the rows in order of Mydate. You need a row number in order the group them in threes